# How to calculate the distance between point and a polyline along specific direction?

Tags: arcpy, python, distance, road

[image]

I want to find the closest road for **point star**. By using the Near tool in ArcMap, I can get the closet distance **a** since the closest road is **road 1**. However, following the red arrow direction, the closest road is **road 2**.

I am just wondering does anybody know any function in arcpy or other libraries that can calculate **distance b**.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking for help writing code should include a snippet of the code you've already tried, and details of what happens when you try it.  You can [edit] your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the road based on Bearing, then you can translate below steps into code:

- Draw a virtual line from start point (A) to specific distance while taking into consideration the bearing. [Bearing Distance to line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/bearing-distance-to-line.htm)
- Virtual line will intersect with Road # 2 (it may be several intersections)
- Export Intersections as feature class of type **POINT**. [Intersections](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm)
- Get the nearest point from Output feature class to Point A. [Near Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm)

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to create a line from your star to an arbitary point in the direction of your arrow. You would then intersect that line with your line data. You would then have a series of points and you take the nearest. The "to" point could be some distance you know that will always create an intersection, such as the extent of your line dataset.